# caret to only show when hover over dropdown nav

Tags: jquery, html, css

Id like to make my caret only display when my dropdown is active. currently its displaying all the time and would like it not to.

also I would like it if when my dropdown navigation (subnav) is active the content below (rest of the website) to drop down too. I mean so my subnav is not overlapping the content.

UPDATE:
sorted out the caret on active

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: Please post your code or create a quick jsfiddle, it helps when people are trying to answer.

Comment: All I need to work out is when the dropdown is active the main body of content drops down with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun I made up this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KghK4/1/).

It adds a triangle added to the first child of the dropdown on a hover css.

CSS

```
#nav li:hover li:first-child:after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 12px solid yellow;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    top: 0px;
    left: 10px;
}
```